Power apps Business process flow
When users are using a business process flow on their forms, I want to stop them selecting the stages out of sequence and before all mandatory information is collected for the previous stage.  So, when they click on the stage circle, I want a message coming up saying to proceed you need to do/provide "blah" first.
I thought I could do this using a workflow that runs prior to the data steps in the stage. I can test for the missing data and stop the process. But this looks like it only stops the workflow process as the BPF continues and will display the input form for the next stage.
It seems like something like this functionality would often be needed to enforce strict process steps. So, I'm surprised it isn't baked in.   Is there a way to achieve this functionality
Erick.

There are two different things. Users are allowed to click around/navigate around without filling all the required fields (steps) in current active stage, whereas they cannot move the process to the future stage or make any other stage as active stage without filling the required fields. Make sense?

This is how it is designed, we can do some scripting/coding/workflow to automate the movement, in case you want to hide the next stage until users fill in the mandatory fields, you may have to think about hide/show sections in form itself.
